# jQuery show or hide on click scrolls to page top

Tags: jquery

I have

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#closesrch").click( function (e) {
e.stopPropagation();
$(this).parent().parent().hide();
});

$("#basemaplink").click( function () {
$(".maplist").toggle('fast');
});
});
</script>

<div class="searches">
 <div class="advsearch">
      <a href="#" id="closesrch"><img src="images/icon_close.png" alt="close"></a>
      ADVANCED PROPERTY SEARCH
 </div>
 Contents here...
</div>


<div class="basemapdiv">
 <a href="#" id="basemaplink"><img src="images/btn_basemap.png" alt="basemap" class="basemapbtn"></a>
 <div class="maplist" style="display:none;">
 Contents here...
 </div>
</div>
```

When the links are clicked it performs the show / hide functions but scrolls to top of the page because of

```
<a href="#"></a>
```

What should be modified to prevent page scrolling?

Thank you,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the links from

```
<a href="#"></a>
```

to

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);"></a>
```

This has the link call a dead end javascript function instead of navigating to the site.com/# url.

---

Other common ways to prevent jumping to the top of the page are:

Return false on the javascript handler. This prevents the default behavior of the link.

```
$('#blahblah').on('click', function(){
    // your code
    return false; // prevents the page jump
});
```

---

or just call preventDefault()

```
<a href="#" id="blahblah"></a>

$('#blahblah').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // your code
});
```

---

or this

```
<a href="javascript: false;"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `stopPropagation()`, use [`preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).

Comment: It works for the first link only. Basemap link scrolls to top.

Comment: You can add it to your `#basemaplink` `click()` handler to prevent it from scrolling to the top. Just make sure to pass in the event like you did for `#closesrch`.

Comment: @Paramasivan You have to add e.preventDefault() to the $("#basemaplink") click event as well.

Comment: Thank you all for your instant answers